# Происхождение слова "восвояси"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Нашёл два разных источника касательно части этого слова *си.* Не могу понять, чему верить.

В [тексте](http://echo.msk.ru/programs/rusalmanach/586536-echo/) передачи на Эхе Москвы говорится:

> Точнее, это было не слово, а словосочетание. Его писали в три слова: въ своя си. Грамматически «своя» — это винительный падеж множественного числа среднего рода. А ***«си»,*** оказывается, не что иное, как ***усилительная частица,*** которая, оказывается, не всегда употреблялась в этом старославянском обороте.

А в [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B8) находим:

> Из др.-русск. въ своıа (вин. мн. ср. р. от *свой) + ***си «себе»*** (дат. ед., dativus ethicus).

Answer (score 4):

```
 два разных источника касательно части этого слова си. Не могу понять,
чему   верить.
```

Источники разные, а ответ-то один, только чуть другими словами. Это и есть слияние словосочетания в одно слово, слились предлог, вин. пад. местоимения свой = своя + частица СИ из СЕБЕ (иди себе).

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! То есть "си" — это частица, которая означает "себе" и одновременно является усилительной?

Comment: Да, так. Даже не усилительной, а как бы для связки слов

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!