# Сиречь, сиесть, восвояси

Tags: этимология

Что означает "си" в таких словах, как *сиречь*, *сиесть* и *восвояси*?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420774/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%81%d0%b8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *восвояси* *си* — это дат. п. от *сѧ* (рус. *ся*); изначально это слово было выражением, калькированным с греч.: *въ своѩ си*.

*Сиречь*: Фасмер пишет:  из ж. им. ед. *си* «эта» + рѣчь. Си, сь, се ('эта', 'этот', 'это') — местоимения.

В *сиесть*, как легко догадаться, это то же *си*, что и в *сиречь*.

Answer (score 3):

Наречие  восвояси -

> церковнославянское по происхождению (въ своѩси), калька с греческого
>   выражения eis ta idia, где eis — предлог ‘в’, idia  — форма
>   винительного падежа множественного числа существительного
>   idion‘собственность’, ср. idios ‘собственный’. При переводе с
>   греческого использован предлог въ, слово своѩ (субстантивированная
>   форма винительного падежа множественного числа местоимения свои или
>   своѥ ‘свой, свое’), а также си — форма дательного падежа единственного
>   числа возвратного местоимения сѧ. Употребление си в данном случае
>   является болгарской языковой особенностью.

http://rus-et.ru/istoriya-yazyka/istoricheskaya-grammatika/etimologiya-nekotoryh-russkih-narechij/

Мнение Шанского:

> Восвоя́си. Искон. Сращение в одно слово или словосочетания во своя
>   вьси «в свои деревни, домой», или оборота во своя си «к себе».

https://shansky.lexicography.online/%D0%B2/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%B8

Значит, **СИ здесь частица -** застывший дат.падеж местоимения ( к себе) или остаток от "веси" - деревни. И то и другое вполне возможно. Словосочетание во своя  вьси «в свои деревни, домой» могло сначала в разговоре сократиться в оборот "во своя си"  - иди к себе домой, возвращайся, а потом появилось значение "иди себе" (в смысле - иди и никого не трогай). В любом случае **это частица**,  ведь в "иди себе" **себе** - частица.

Сиречь и сиесть - пояснительные союзы,например: *«Арифметика, сиречь Наука числителная с разных диалектов на словнський язык преведена и водино собрана и на две книги разделена... ныне же на свет произведена... 1719... месяца июля в 13 день»;  «Катихизис, си есть Словеса наставленные, или огласительные, на вся праздники» Феодора Студита; «Денница премудрости, то есть о трех началах или источник и начало всех вещей в таинстве премудрости... В печать отдано. Франкфурт и Лейпциг 1762 года»;*

Получается, сиречь - си + речь = эта речь (эта же речь = современное знач.  **вернее говоря, иначе говоря**); сиесть - си + есть = то есть.

Употреблялись полные формы  местоимений (сии > сеи, сиia, сиѥ) и краткие,энклитические (безударные) (ми, ти, си; мѧ , тѧ,сѧ; ны, вы).. В косвенных падежах они имели одинаковые окончания, за исключением вин. пад. ед. ч. женского рода: сю и сию).

СИ в союзах - **указательное местоимение** - сь (этот), си (эта), се (это).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90171/discussion-on-answer-by----).